# JavaFX Line Chart NumberAxis with strict upper bound, need padding of one tick like CategoryAxis does automatically

Tags: user-interface, javafx, charts

So I'm creating a Line Chart with an undetermined number of XYChart.Series'.  The xAxis is a CategoryAxis and the yAxis is a NumberAxis.  The problem I have is that I need to have an upper bound max of 100 on the yAxis as it represents %. When a series is plotted which hits the top 100, the circle point is clipped by the boundaries of the chart area. See the picture.

[MyChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFL2m.png)

The same thing does NOT happen with the xAxis natively it seems (because I didn't set an upper bound?) and I'd like to achieve the same effect where it looks like there is an extra tick of padding between the upper bound and the chart's edge, but without a tick label.  Setting the upper bound on the yAxis to 105 makes it look like upper bound IS 105, which is not an acceptable workaround.

This is how I instantiate the axes:

```
this.xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
this.yAxis =  new NumberAxis("Percent", 0.0, 100.0, 10.0);
```

The Line chart is built like so and then added to the parent node which is the center of a BorderLayout:

```
LineChart<String, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(this.xAxis, this.yAxis);

List<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> seriesList = null;

if (seriesMap.containsKey(this.unitNameForChart)) {
  seriesList = seriesMap.get(this.unitNameForChart);
}
else {
  seriesList = buildTimeStepSeries();
}
lineChart.getData().addAll(seriesList);
...
```

I've tried adding padding/insets directly to the LineChart and yAxis yet nothing worked out. I'm open for CSS or direct coding solutions.